# How to test asynchronous function with rtl and jest in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my asynchronous submit function on my form using RTL and Jest but encounter some errors along the way. By the way, this is my first time testing my code so I'm quite confused about everything regarding the testing procedures.

Here is my error:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0

  34 |
  35 |         fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('submitBtn'))
> 36 |         expect(submitTodo).toHaveBeenCalled()
     |                            ^
  37 |     })
  38 | })
```

Below is my code that checks my form.

```
it('checks the function submitTodo', () => {
    const submitTodo = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(<InputField submitTodo={submitTodo} />);
    const input = getByTestId('input');
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'test' } })

    fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('submitBtn'))
    expect(submitTodo).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

and here is my form alongside with my function.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { firestore } from 'firebase/firebaseConfig';
import firebase from 'firebase/firebaseConfig';
import styles from 'theme/main.module.scss';

const InputField = () => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');

  const submitTodo = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await firestore.collection('todo').add({
        todo,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
    setTodo('');
  };
  return (
    <form
      data-testid='form'
      className={styles.inputFieldContainer}
      onSubmit={(e) => submitTodo(e)}
    >
      <input
        data-testid='input'
        className={styles.inputFieldContainer__input}
        placeholder='Please enter a todo.'
        required
        value={todo}
        onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        data-testid='submitBtn'
        className={styles.inputFieldContainer__btn}
        type='submit'
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

Comment: shouldn't you call `click` on your button?

Comment: Hi @HunterMcMillen, as far as I know that would be redundant if I have type="submit" and add additional onClick again.

Comment: The biggest point of using RTL is to interact with your component via its API, i.e. its props and UI. You should probably test form submission via clicking the submit button. The `InputField` component also doesn't consume a `submitTodo` prop, so creating a jest function and passing it really accomplishes nothing. Mock the `firestore` object and assert it has been called.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, thanks for the reply. Will it be okay if you show me some code regarding with mocking the firestore object? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens usually when there is some async action within the code that is being tested. So the test completes before the async method returns.

Jest has many ways to test async functions mentioned in their documentation. But one of the straightforward ways is to use the done callback.

So your code for the test would be like

```
it('checks the function submitTodo', (done) => {
    const submitTodo = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(<InputField submitTodo={submitTodo} />);
    const input = getByTestId('input');
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'test' } })

    expect.assertions(1);

    fireEvent.submit(getByTestId('submitBtn'))
    expect(submitTodo).toHaveBeenCalled()
    done();    
})
```

The done() callback ensures that jest will wait until the done callback is made.Also the expect.assertions ensures that the assertion is actually made and fails if the assertion is not made.

More details and documentation can be found from the [official jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous)